# Problema al hacer una consulta con el MATCH y AGAINTS en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo el siguiente problema es que deseo realizar una busqueda de usuarios, con el uso del `match againts` y es el siguiente fragmente de código.

```
SELECT
  pur.url_product, us.Name,us.LastName, pur.fecha_compra,
  count.Name_country, ci.Name_city, pur.status_compra, pur.type_compra,
  MATCH(us.Name,us.LastName)  AGAINST("jhon mrurillo") AS names 
FROM compras pur 
INNER JOIN users us ON pur.id_user = us.id_users 
INNER JOIN countrys count ON pur.id_country = count.id_country 
INNER JOIN citys_ ci ON pur.id_city = ci.id_city 
WHERE MATCH(us.Name, us.LastName) AGAINST("jhon murillo")
```

En cual estoy tratando que me muestre el  registro del usuario con el nombre *jhon murillo* y se presenta el problema de que, cuando va mostrar los datos, debido a que existe un usuario con el nombre *jhon carillo* y me lo enseña también. Que por obvias razones no lo debería hacer.
¿Cómo soluciono eso?

Comment: ¿Se podría saber por qué no usas un simple `WHERE us.Name='jhon' AND us.LastName='murillo'`, eso sí, bien escrito el apellido :-)?

Answer (score 0):

Las consultas que usan `MATCH` y `AGAINST` se conocen como consultas `FULLTEXT` o de texto completo, y tienen un uso muy determinado: **buscar todas las ocurrencias de los valores buscados en campos generalmente grandes, como campos del tipo `TEXT`**.

Para que te hagas a una idea, una consulta de este tipo serviría para encontrar ciertas palabras o frases en un libro o en el capítulo de un libro almacenado en una columna del tipo `TEXT`.

La [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) define así este tipo de búsqueda:

> La búsqueda de texto completo (`FULLTEXT`) se realiza usando la
>   sintaxis `MATCH () ... AGAINST`. `MATCH()` toma una lista separada por
>   comas que nombra las columnas para buscar. `AGAINST` toma una cadena
>   para buscar y un modificador opcional que indica qué tipo de búsqueda
>   realizar. La cadena de búsqueda debe ser un valor de cadena que sea
>   constante durante la evaluación de la consulta. Esto descarta, por
>   ejemplo, una columna de tabla porque puede diferir para cada fila.

Para aplicar este tipo de consultas hay algunas restricciones que afectan también a la tabla y que no conviene aplicar bajo ningún concepto, a no ser que necesites realmente hacer búsquedas de este tipo.

Dichas restricciones son:

- La tabla debe tener un índice de texto completo (`FULLTEXT`), que debe ser indicado en el `CREATE TABLE` o posteriormente.
- Los índices de texto completo solo se pueden usar con tablas `InnoDB` o `MyISAM`, y solo se pueden crear para columnas `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` o `TEXT`.
- Para grandes conjuntos de datos, es mucho más rápido cargar sus datos en una tabla que no tiene índice `FULLTEXT` y luego crear el índice después de eso, que cargar datos en una tabla que tiene un índice `FULLTEXT` existente.

Esta última afirmación, como todas las demás, puede dejar entrever con toda claridad el grave error que podría ser dotar a una tabla de un índice `FULLTEXT` solamente para buscar un nombre y un apellido.

---

### Optar por la solución clásica

En tu caso, considero que optar por la solución de toda la vida sería lo correcto. Si tú quieres los registros cuyo nombre sea `X` y cuyo apellido sea `Y`, puedes hacerlo con un `WHERE`, como siempre se ha hecho:

```
SELECT
  pur.url_product, us.Name,us.LastName, pur.fecha_compra,
  count.Name_country, ci.Name_city, pur.status_compra, pur.type_compra
FROM compras pur 
INNER JOIN users us ON pur.id_user = us.id_users 
INNER JOIN countrys count ON pur.id_country = count.id_country 
INNER JOIN citys_ ci ON pur.id_city = ci.id_city 
WHERE us.Name='jhon' AND us.LastName='murillo';
```

Ahora bien, si quieres buscar listas de palabras en los capítulos del libro de Jhon Murillo, entonces sí, podrías plantearte dotar a la tabla `libros_completos` de un índice `FULLTEXT`.

¡That's all!

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias, me fue muy útil esa informacion

Comment: Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda, @JhonDemberMurilloMendez