# ¿Como realizar una busqueda fulltext en mysql?

Tags: mysql

veran, se como hacerla con MATCH AGAINST, pero no me reconoce numeros, por ejemplo:
si tengo una tabla:
productos

id  | producto           | puertas

1   | carro Toyota       | dos

2   | Corolla            | 4

si la busqueda que hiciera fuera: "carro 4 puertas"
la consulta que usaria seria esta:

select id, producto from productos where MATCH(producto,descripcion) AGAINST('carro 4 puertas');

Pero solo me mostraria el carro toyota, no me funciona con numeros.
Tienen una idea de como hacerla funcionar?

Comment: Para empezar creo que tu modelo de datos no esta bien, no es correcto que para un atributo puedas guardar "dos" y "2" debes de definir si es de una forma o si es de otra, ademas creo que si tu tabla es de vehículos deberias de tener un atributo marca y otro atributo modelo.

Comment: claro yo se, en realidad la tabla que uso no es de carros, pero quisiera saber si es posible resolver ese problema.

Comment: Aún así creo que no deberia de existir esa disyuntiva.

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas modificando [este modelo de datos](http://rextester.com/RBII91393) y no veo ningún problema. En tu pregunta la columna se llama `puertas` y en la consulta usas la columna `descripcion`  ¿será por eso que no te trae los datos? ¿Realmente las dos columnas que contienen los datos tienen un índice `FULLTEXT`?  Incluso pienso que un índice `FULLTEXT` no es justificado en este caso.

Comment: pues en la tabla real que uso si uso los campos correctos, pero si coloco un numero en ese string, no me muestra esa fila que contenga solo ese numero

Comment: tendrías que aplicar un filtro que convierta números a letras para el caso "dos" y por cuestiones de índices el "4" lo tendrías que buscar con un like ó crear una columna con numeros, fulltext search está pensado para palabras, no números, no sub strings

Comment: Por otra parte, no creo que en este caso sea justificado usar índices `FULLTEXT`.  [Te dejo esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159617/29967), por si puede orientar en algo sobre este tipo de índices y su conveniencia o no.

Comment: no se si me entiendes, si te fijas en el ejemplo(que no es el mas adecuado), en la segunda fila solo coincide el 4 con mi string de busqueda. ese no lo toma en cuenta.

Comment: es que "4" no es una palabra, "dos" si

Comment: no todo está perdido: con datos mas cercanos a tu situación/requerimiento se pueden hacer consideraciones, ver como manejar indices extra o consultas extra.