# búsquedas combinadas sql & php

Tags: sql

tengo este fragmento de código que es parte de una classe. Si el usuario escribe una palabra la búsqueda usará %like%, si el usuario escribe varias palabras usará match against. El código funciona bien, pero no es lo que yo quiero porque el match against busca de manera independiente los posts titulados para cada una de la dos palabras, y no de forma combinada, títulos con ambas palabras.  Mi idea es que sea de manera combinada, qué sentencia se usaría para ello?? Gracias

```
if ( !empty($q['s']) )
        {
        $q['s'] = addslashes_gpc($q['s']);
        $search = ' AND ';
        $q['s'] = preg_replace('/, +/', ' ', $q['s']);
        $q['s'] = str_replace(',', ' ', $q['s']);
        $q['s'] = str_replace('"', ' ', $q['s']);
        $q['s'] = trim($q['s']);

        $n = '%';
        $palabras=explode(" ",$q['s']);
        $numero=count($palabras);
if ($numero==1) {
            $q['s'] = $wpdb->escape(trim($q['s']));
                $search .= '(titulo LIKE \''. $n. $q['s']. $n. '\') ';
        } 
    elseif ($numero>1) 
        {

        $search .= " MATCH (titulo) AGAINST ('{$q['s']}')"; 
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las consultas que usan `MATCH` y `AGAINST`, conocidas como consultas `FULLTEXT` o de texto completo, tienen un uso muy determinado: **buscar todas las ocurrencias de los valores buscados en campos generalmente grandes, como campos del tipo `TEXT`.**

Servirían por ejemplo para buscar ciertas palabras en un capítulo de un libro o en un libro completo, pero para una columna simple no se recomienda usar `MATCH ... AGAINST`. Esto podría ralentizar tu base de datos, porque hay ciertas restricciones que se deben aplicar a las columnas de la tabla sobre las que vas a aplicar este tipo de consultas. Para más detalles sobre esto, puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159617/29967), donde he traducido parte de la documentación de MySQL al respecto.

Para tu caso bastaría con un simple `... LIKE ... AND LIKE  ...`, el `AND` es para satisfacer tu requerimiento de *buscar de forma combinada*. Si fuese uno u otro, sólo tienes que cambiar el `AND` por un `OR`.

Por ejemplo:

```
if ( !empty($q['s']) )
        {
        $q['s'] = addslashes_gpc($q['s']);
        $search = ' AND ';
        $q['s'] = preg_replace('/, +/', ' ', $q['s']);
        $q['s'] = str_replace(',', ' ', $q['s']);
        $q['s'] = str_replace('"', ' ', $q['s']);
        $q['s'] = trim($q['s']);

        $n = '%';
        $palabras=explode(" ",$q['s']);
        $numero=count($palabras);
if ($numero==1) {
            $q['s'] = $wpdb->escape(trim($q['s']));
                $search .= '(titulo LIKE \''. $n. $q['s']. $n. '\') ';
        } 
    elseif ($numero>1) 
        {

        $search .= " AND (titulo LIKE '$n{$q['s']}$n')"; 
        } 

}
```

He asumido que `$n` es el comodín. Dado que no estoy en tu contexto, corrige lo que haga falta en la sintaxis en caso de que algo se me haya escapado.

Comment: Ya entiendo. El problema es que busca las palabras como una sola frase pero no arroja resultados si las palabras no están unidas aunque estén en el mismo enunciado o título. por ejemplo si busco "tierra nadie" no arrojará resultados aunque haya un título con la frase "tierra de nadie", mientras que si busco "tierra de" o "de nadie", si arrojará resultado. Tal vez con un explode y que cada liike consecutivo fuera una palabra...

Comment: @Texas Mejor que con un `explode`, puedes valerte de los comodines posibles que admite `LIKE`, o bien valerte de expresiones regulares, dependiendo del tipo de criterio que quieras armar. [Revisa la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) y los diferentes ejemplos, para que te puedas formar un criterio y decidir qué es mejor para tu caso.